# Angular - onClick trigger menu on another component

Tags: angular, drop-down-menu, components

I have created two components. The first one contains a button and the second a dropdown menu.
When the user clicks on this button (on the first component) I want to display the menu (on the second component).

Is it possible (and how?) to "call" the menu from the component where the button is or should I merge them in the same component?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: You can connected thoses components via eventEmitters or a service instance

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Yes, it is possible, you can make use of `BehaviorSubject` from rxjs.

Create a service file, e.g custom.service.ts:

```
buttonClickSubject: Subject<Boolean> = new BehaviorSubject(null);

buttonClick$: Observable<Boolean> = this.buttonClickSubject.asObservable();
```

Comp A (on button click, call `next()` of `Subject`):

```
 this.service.buttonClickSubject.next(true);
```

Comp B (inside `constructor` subscribe to the `Observable`):

```
this.service.buttonClick.subscribe(data => {
  //write you menu code here
});
```

Answer to your 2nd Question :

Its completely depends on your design. If your Menu `Component` is large enough and you can resue in diff places, then you can definitely create a new `Component` else no need.